# Проверка формы на ввод символов

Tags: php

Доброго времени суток! Подскажите, пожалуйста, ответ.

Есть форма ввода. Пользователь вводит число в форму. Если число совпало, с тем что в базе, то выдаем: число правильное. Иначе, число не правильное. Вопрос: как сделать, чтобы выдавало предупреждение: "в поле не введенно число", если пользователь не ввел число, и нажал кнопку "далее". Код ниже.

```
<?
if (empty($_POST['chislo'])) {
    echo '<form action="?" method="post"><div>     
    Число:<br/><input type="text" name="chislo" maxlength="40" title="Введите      число"><br>   
    <input type="submit" value="Проверка" title="Проверка"/></div></form>';
} else{ 
    $chi = intval($_POST['chislo']); //фильтр
} else {
    $chislo = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT `ch` FROM `chislo`")); // база.
    if ($chi == $chislo['ch']) {
        echo 'число правильное';
    } else {
        echo 'число не правильное';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Что это за страшный кошмар?  Откуда два else подряд?

А проверку на то, что число не введено при нажатии кнопки, надо делать на JavaScript

Comment: Photon , мне нужна проверка средствами php.

Comment: для html5 используйте атрибут required (поле должно быть заполнено). На php обычную проверку. И проверка на javascript на числовость.

Или вам нужно помощь в реализации?

Answer (score 2):

Ну если на PHP, тогда так:

```
if (!isset($_POST['test'])) {     
?>
<form action="" method="post">
   <div>     
       Число:<br/><input type="text" name="chislo" maxlength="40" title="Введите      число"><br>   
       <input type="submit" name="test" value="Проверка" title="Проверка"/>
   </div>
</form>
<?php
}
elseif (isset($_POST['test']) && trim($_POST['chislo']) == "") {
    echo "Не введено число";
}
else{
   $chi = intval($_POST['chislo']); //фильтр
   $chislo=mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT `ch` FROM `chislo`")); // база.
   if($chi==$chislo['ch']){     
      echo'число правильное';     
   }     
   else {    
      echo 'число не правильное';     
   }     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так:

```
<?php
$number = $_POST['chislo'];
$number_from_bd = 123; // число из базы

if($_POST['submit']) {
 if(isset($number)) {
  if($number == $number_from_bd) echo 'Число правильное';
  else echo 'Число неправильное';
 } else echo 'Введите число';
}
?>

<form action="?" method="post">     
 Число: <br/>
 <input type="text" name="chislo" maxlength="40" title="Введите число">
 <br>   
 <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Проверка" title="Проверка"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ',' or ';'  on line 24

    <?

     } else echo 'Введите число';
    ?>

Comment: Круто, а я злобный хацкер и бахну в поле '1' или 1 пробел, и чё будем делать?

Comment: @Borisov_, отредактировал пост.

Comment: @Genchik, не подумал. Но тут можно обойтись функцией trim(). Это о пробелах. А про проверку на ввод именно числа, речи не шло.

Answer (score 1):

Вам выпадающее окно нужно или что?

Там где у вас

echo 'число не правильное';   
затем

```
echo "<script>alert('Введите число правильно!')</script>";
```

Answer (score 1):

`else echo 'Число неправильное'` ну просто человек не поставил точку с запятой.

```
else echo 'Число неправильное';
```

Answer (score 1):

Так тоже можно + добавить фильтр на php и всё будет гуд:

```
<input type="text" name="chislo" maxlength="40" title="Введите число" required>
```